# Saturation vapor pressure effect on human body

Tags: breathing, environment, blood-pressure

I found this calculator:
http://www.decatur.de/javascript/dew/
It calculates the dew point based on temperature and humidity. 
In the result it is mentioned the saturation vapor pressure.

I barely understand the notions of vapor pressure, but I read somewhere that divers are rising back to water surface slowly, because the vapor pressure has negative effects on blood vessels, which can pop.

My goal is to find if a similar situation  (like divers' one) can be encountered by runners who are exercising when the vapor pressure is very high.

Thoughts?

Edit:
Is it possible to experience the effects of diving 10 meters in water, at surface with the contribution of climate factors (humidity, temperature and atmospheric pressure)?

Comment: Welcome to Biology and thanks for your question. Divers encounter problems with gas bubbles, known as ['the bends', divers' disease, or Caisson disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness). It has to do with gas pressures under a column of water versus those at the surface. Nitrogen accumulates at low depths, oxygen starts to accumulate at ~30 m etc etc. It has little, if anything to do with cells popping afaik. Further and quite frankly, I don't understand your question... Could you add references or sources to your claims?

Comment: If the divers then rise up back to the surface too quickly, these gases will be forced out of their dissolved form and form bubbles in the blood vessels. These gas bubbles can then cause the blood vessels to pop, causing much physical pain and serious medical issues.  << An excerpt from http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Phases_of_Matter/Liquids/Vapor_Pressure .My question is, is it possible to replicate the situation of divers by a person who is running in certain weather conditions?

Comment: Your question said "blood cells." The reference you give says "blood vessels." Blood vessels are made of endothelial cells, and the gas bubbles don't rupture the cells, it breaks the junctions between the cells causing blood to leak into the surrounding tissue. If the blood vessel that bursts happens to be in the brain, then that is a stroke and there is a good chance the person will die unless the rupture can be repaired. While it is possible that a person's own (high) blood pressure could cause a small capillary to rupture, variations in normal atmospheric pressure will not do it.

Comment: Thanks @AMR So, if I understand correctly, if the atmospheric pressure is very high, maybe above 800 mmHg, the humidity is 100%, temperature above 35 degrees Celsius and a person is exercising at lactate threshold, the diver's conditions are almost similar. Is that correct?

Comment: The problem is not the pressure itself, it is a rapid change in pressure.